# NgBootstrap modal with correct style classes

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I am using `NgBootstrap` in Angular for creating modals. In the HTML, I have the following template.

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="add-item-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header wo-modal_update-address-header">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <img class="wo-modal_update-address-icon" src="assets/img/add.svg">
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Create Release</h4>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <form>
```

Now I am using the `<ngtemplate>` as follows :

```
<ng-template #release let-modal>
    <div id="add-item-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header wo-modal_update-address-header">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <img class="wo-modal_update-address-icon" src="assets/images/add.svg">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Create Release</h4>
                    </div>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div>
```

The modal is appearing, but the class `modal-xl` is not added correctly and therefore, the size of the modal is appears to be small. I have checked a few implementations of the `NgBootstrap` and for them, `modal-content` is added just after `<ngtemplate>`. But in that case how the classes can be added correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's when you open the pop where you indicate in options, the size, see the [docs about open](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModal)

```
this.modalService.open(MyComponent, 
    { scrollable: true, 
      size: 'lg' })
```